# How to check the given input is string or integer?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to check the given input is string or integer?

Ex

if i'm giving my input as "vinoth".

i want my output like this

"It is a string".

if i'm giving my input as 123.

i want my output like this

"It is a integer".

Comment: first output is string not character.

Answer (score 0):

```
string st = "your string";
int number = 0;
bool result = int.TryParse(st , out number );
```

if `result` is true then it is number else string.

You can do same for different numeric types also.

Comment: because the core was wrong, but now you change it